# Eloquent one to one relation with two custom fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables that should have One-to-one relation. 
I know that Laravel automatically gets relations based on the field name. But I should state the field name if it's different. So I did that way but still get **null** as a resort. Anyone see what I cant see?

**Table op**

```
id
operator
departure
arrival
```

**Table op_parameters**

```
id
price
unit
```

**In my Op Controller**

```
class Op extends Model
```

{

```
public function opParameter()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\OpParameter', 'id');
}
```

**In my opParameter Controller**

```
   class OpParameter extends Model
{
    //
    public static $table = "op_parameters";

    /*
     *  One to one relation
     */
    public function op()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Op', 'id');
    }
}
```

And when I try to dump values like

```
dd(Op::find(1)->price);
```

it returns

> null

Sadly, I cannot change table names or fields. So what seems to be the problem? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Are your models inside a Model folder? Or are they in the root of your app folder?

Comment: They are both inside app/Models directory @MattMcDonald

Comment: And are you using the operator key in your op table to reference the id in your op_parameters table?

Comment: In the controller, which I dd this value 

use App\Model\Op;
use App\Model\OpParameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need something like this, I've presumed that the operator field on the op table is the reference to the id on the op_parameters table (otherwise I can't see what you might be using to link the two tables).

```
<?php
class Op extends Model {

    public function opParameter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\OpParameter', 'id', 'operator');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
class OpParameter extends Model {

    protected $table = "op_parameters";

    public function op()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Op', 'operator');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
dd(Op::find(1)->opParameter->price);
```

There are a couple of problems with what you currently have.

First, when you're defining your relationships you're not specifying what the custom key you're using is.

Second, when you try to reference the price you're not going via the relationship you've defined.

Comment: Actually, id table on the op table is the reference to the op_parameters table @MattMcDonald